# How to wait if the first code is under execution?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have a situation where a user creates the instance of a class when the user clicks on a tabitem. This class contains a function which plots a graph and it's very time consuming so it is written async.

Now the problem is lets say the user first time click on tab and the class instantiates and the long process works for long time and meanwhile where the previous async task is not finshed and the user clicked again on the same tabitem.

In this situation i must wait until the previous async task is not finished and then on second click to tabitem must create instance after teh fist async task is finshed (It should wait until the first async process is not finshed).

The code is here:

```
if (selectedTabIndex == 2) //What is the user selected second time whil the previous task is still not finshed ? 
{         
    DrawGraph obj= new DrawGraph(selectedItem.Name);
 }
```

Somewhere in DrawGraph class constructor i have done:

```
 public DrawGraph(string Name)
 {
   timeConsumingProcess(Name);
 }

 public async void timeConsumingProcess(string Name)
 {       
   await  startTaimeConsumingProcess();
 }
```

What i want is when user clicks the second time this tab item number=2 then it must wait until the previous async task to finsh and then it must instantiate  again DrawGraph class to 
  restart async again.

How to achieve it ?

Comment: Why not disable the tab?

Comment: @HristoYankov Yeah  i had that idea but that was not accepted by my senior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this situation i must wait until the previous async task is not finished and then on second click to tabitem must create instance after teh fist async task is finshed

Then have your code (a)wait on the last task:

```
private Task drawGraph = null;
...
if (selectedTabIndex == 2)
{
  if (drawGraph != null)
    await drawGraph;
  DrawGraph obj = new DrawGraph(selectedItem.Name);
  drawGraph = obj.timeConsumingProcess();
}

...

private readonly string name;
public DrawGraph(string Name)
{
  name = Name;
}

public async Task timeConsumingProcess()
{
  await  startTaimeConsumingProcess();
}
```

Note that this requires you to use `async Task` instead of `async void`, which is good anyway because you should [avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If it is a very time consuming process, you can choose to do it in a different thread

```
public DrawGraph(string Name)
{
    var task = new Task(() => timeConsumingProcess(Name));
    task.Start();
}
```

This way your main thread won't be blocked. If you want to run some code after this long running task is finished, use the ContinueWith method.

```
public DrawGraph(string Name)
{
    _canPressTab = false;
    var task = new Task(() => timeConsumingProcess(Name));
    task.Start();
    task.ContinueWith(t => {
        _canPressTab = true;
        ...
    });
}
```

UPDATE BELOW

As seen here, you can call the Draw method when you click on a tab. This checks if a task is already running. If not, it starts the task. If the task is running it will wait on it for it to complete and then start a new task.

```
    public Task task = new Task(DoSomething);
    private static void DoSomething()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }


    private void Draw()
    {
        //if tab is clicked run the Draw method
        if (task.Status.Equals(TaskStatus.Running))
        {
            task.Wait();
            task = new Task(DoSomething);
            task.Start();
        }
        else if (task.Status.Equals(TaskStatus.RanToCompletion))
        {
            task = new Task(DoSomething);
            task.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            task.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What i have to do is to wait in if (selectedTabIndex == 2) condition while the previosu task is proocessing. If processing then let it finshed then processed the next instance. How to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the Task representing the long running action in an instance variable in the form and use this to check whether the task is still running.

```
private Task drawGraphTask = null;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DrawGraph();
}

private async void DrawGraph()
{
    // Only perform task when this is the first time 
    // or the previous task is already completed
    if (drawGraphTask == null || drawGraphTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        drawGraphTask = startTimeConsumingProcess();
        await drawGraphTask;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Task already active");
    }
}

private Task startTimeConsumingProcess()
{
    // Your Code here
    return Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

It is not good to start an asynchronous activity from inside a constructor. Move the asynchronous logic outside the DrawGraph class and make instantiating the class asynchronous at the level of the form already.

Comment: the condition drawGraphTask == null will even execute for the second click  because the parameter on debuging after second click are these "Id = 744, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}"" but it still execute thsi condition

Comment: No, the condition checks whether the Task as a whole is null, it doesn't matter what value the Method property of the task has.

Answer (score -1):

A simple change will achieve this

```
public async Task DrawGraph(string Name)
{
    await timeConsumingProcess(Name);
}

public async Task timeConsumingProcess(string Name)
{       
    await startTaimeConsumingProcess();
}
```

I made `DrawGraph()` return a `Task` as well in case you need to await it.

Comment: Using await does not prevent handling of user actions, so the problem remains.

Comment: @NineBerry you're right. But that's not what the user asked. The user asked for the task to await even though the button had been pressed. So the next call to `DrawGraph()` will await the previous one completing.